# How to retrieve the device version and platform in the PhoneGap Application?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, iphone, cordova

I'm using the Phone Gap(Cordova 2.5.0).I need to find the device details (Is Android or Iphone) , where the application is running. By this ,I want to load  pages as per the device
Example: Page 1 without Back button loaded in to android and Page 1 with Back button loaded to Iphone (slider, navigation etc)

My code ,header files are

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

How I find the device and load page  as per device using cordova?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device object describes the device's hardware and software.
You have to include some permissions for in your config.xml.

Refer this [**LINK**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device)

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

    element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Model: '    + device.model     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this phonegap plugin device.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

You can follow step by step how to setup your plugin into your project.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/doc/index.md